# Having difficulty in constructing SQL query for events

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem where I'm trying to get counts of data associated with multiple events occurring on separate days.

Let's say I'm following a group of plane-spotters, each of whom may spot many planes from around the world on any one day, while based at some particular airport. I'd like to produce a list consisting of one row per spotter per day, with columns for the spotter's ID, the date, how many planes he (it's always "he", right?) spotted on that day, how many individual airlines the planes belonged to, and how many countries the airlines belonged to. So, I'd like to have results like this:

```
 +-----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
 |           |            |  Planes |          |   Airline |
 | SpotterID | Date       | spotted | Airlines | Countries |
 +-----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
 |      1234 | 2017-04-15 |      28 |       11 |         4 |
 +-----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
 |      1234 | 2017-04-16 |      65 |       19 |         7 |
 +-----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
 |      5678 | 2017-04-22 |      39 |       14 |         6 |
 +-----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
 |      6677 | 2017-04-28 |      74 |       29 |         9 |
 +-----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

So, (MySQL 5.7.17) my test tables are as sketched out below (I may have forgotten a couple of indexes).

The plane-spotting events table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `SpottingEvents` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `SpotterID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `SpotDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `PlaneID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Notes` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `indx_SpotterID_PlaneID_DateTime` (`SpotterID`,`PlaneID`,`SpotDateTime`),
 KEY `indx_SpotterID_DateTime` (`SpotterID`,`SpotDateTime`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

the planes table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `Planes` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `PlaneID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `PlaneTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `AirlineID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Notes` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `indx_PlaneID_AirlineID` (`PlaneID`,`AirlineID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

the airlines table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `Airlines` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `AirlineID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `AirlineName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `CountryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Notes` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `indx_AirlineID` (`AirlineID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and the countries table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `Countries` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `CountryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `CountryName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Notes` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `indx_CountryID` (`CountryID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

My problem is with the last two columns, the Airlines and Countries counts. I've tried several ways to do this, including the following:

```
select distinct sev.SpotDateTime, sev.SpotterID, count(*) as planes_count,
(select count(*) from ( select distinct cnt.CountryID 
  from Countries as cnt
  inner join Airlines as aln on al.CountryID = cnt.CountryID
  inner join Planes as pl on pl.AirlineID = aln.AirlineID 
  where pl.PlaneID = sev.PlaneID ) as t1) as countries_count  
from SpottingEvents as sev
# where sev.UserID = 1234
group by SpotDateTime
order by SpotDateTime
```

which leads to an error `Unknown column 'sev.planeID' in 'where clause'`
but since I'm no expert, I'm just not  getting the intended results. So, how do I achieve the desired results?

Comment: Can you share the query which you tried?

Comment: Nearly, but see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Edited my question to show a sample query which results in an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `COUNT(DISTINCT)`. Join the tables needed, then count.

```
select
  se.spotterid,
  date(se.spotdatetime) as spot_date,
  count(*) as planes,
  count(distinct p.airlineid) as airlines,
  count(distinct a.countryid) as countries
from spottingevents se
join planes p on p.planeid = se.planeid
join airlines a on a.airlineid = p.airlineid
group by se.spotterid, date(se.spotdatetime)
order by date(se.spotdatetime), se.spotterid;
```

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect, thankyou Thorsten! I'm going to have to study this carefully, since I'll be needing this kind of thing in the future.I hasten to add that it's not about plane-spotters, but IS to do with participants pursuing events in a technical hobby. Thanks also to Strawberry for pointing me to the guidelines for posting enquiries like this.